std::partition_copy: what happens when the d_first_true output range overlaps with the input range?
for example:
int original_range[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int copy_here[7];

std::partition_copy(std::begin(original_range), std::end(original_range),
                    std::begin(original_range), std::begin(copy_here),
                    [](int val) { return val >= 4; });

I'm expecting here: original_range = {4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7} and copy_here = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0}
you can assume that the garbage values stored in copy_here are 0.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Please note that only the OP can ultimately confirm whether a dupe target solves their problem or not. Users who do not have relevant gold badges to unilaterally close/reopen a post may edit the post for clarity, but without putting words in the OP's mouth. Remarks about applicability of dupes are best suited for comments. Remarks about the edit process itself don't belong anywhere. Please do not roll back again lest I have to lock the post. If the post is not sufficiently clear/reproducible to determine applicability of dupe targets, then it can be closed as lacking clarity.

Does this answer your question? std::unique_copy with overlapping ranges and unique_copy with overlapping ranges

Your code invokes UB (Undefined Behavior), and therefore anything can happen.
from std::partition_copy documentation:

Among the input range and the two output ranges, if any two ranges
overlap, the behavior is undefined.

(emphasis is mine)
In your case the first output range overlaps with the input range, and so UB ensues. There is no point rationalising about the program output.
Also note that:
int copy_here[7];

leaves the elements uninitialized. If you read those which did not get initialied by the algorithm, you get into another UB.
You can fix it by using:
//--------------vv-
int copy_here[7]{};

This will initialize all elements to zero.

@MarekR sorry for the confusion I meant for you to assume that the array copy_here is initialized with 0, my mistake I shouldn't have been lazy to add it.

@Ellie best way to avoid any confusion is ask question with Unit Test showing the problem (like in links I've provided as comments). Such tests are best way to provide [mcve].
